# How to get current location in android 7?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, locationlistener

I'm trying to get current location in android and its OK when i'm using on android M or lower, But when i run my application on android N, location is null and when i want get latitude from it will returns 0. here is my code

```
 try {

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
             } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                 if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                 if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and its OK when i'm using on android M or lower

No, it is not. `getLastKnownLocation()` frequently returns `null`, on all versions of Android.

`getLastKnownLocation()` is an optimization. Use it, but be prepared to rely upon `onLocationChanged()` for when `getLastKnownLocation()` returns `null` or an out-of-date value.

This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html), as well as in books and courses on Android app development.

Comment: its worked for me on android L ,onLocationChangeListener don't work on android 7 for me too @CommonsWare

Comment: @BehnamEskandari: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Location/Classic) successfully obtains a location on a Google Pixel running Android 7.1. For locations in the US, it will show a weather forecast for that location.

Comment: The main thing that needs to be understood about `getLastKnownLocation()` is that if you recently enabled location on the device, or restarted the device, this will ALWAYS return null, until a location is received on the calling provider (GPS, Network) from ANY app, not just yours. Just because you called `requestLocationUpdates()` doesn't mean you have a location immediately. Also, even if you do get a location from `getLastKnownLocation()`, it doesn't mean it's recent. It could be minutes or hours old.

Answer (score 1):

To get the last known location all your have to do is call

mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
once the location service was connected.

read how to use the new location API

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation